# Move Cursor or Insertion Point To A Specific Page?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, itext

Just started using iTextSharp a week ago - you would think some things would be obvious but apparently not.

I would like to create a PDF report structure (i.e., lines, images and static text) in advance of adding dynamic content using PDFWriter. This report template will be used for three types of reporting.

It means, I build the pages and then I want to go back to page 1 and add some new content, and then go to page 2 and add more content and then go to page 3 and so on and so forth. I will determine the number of pages I need in advance build the template and then add additional content.

I have no problem creating the pages. No problem using GotoLocalPage to get back to Page 1 (or whatever page I may want to call). But all my new direct content I want to add ends up on the last page.

How do I move the cursor or insertion point (for lack of knowledge) to any previous page and begin adding new content?

I've tried Outlines, Bookmarks, Anchors but they all appear to add text to a page - are such things as invisible anchors (i.e., using empty strings?)

I don't want to close the document down and re-open to add additional content - there should be a method to move to any given part of a document and add additional content.

I've added some code as a references - the code is VB.net but I don't have any problems interpreting Java or C# - Sorry I could not add an images StackFlow won't let me because I'm a newbie!

```
Private Sub BuildPDFDocument(ByVal DocType As String, ByVal OutFileName As String, ByVal Pages As Integer)

    OutFile = New Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    OutFile.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate())

    Try

        Using Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(OutFile, New FileStream(WorkingOutputFolder & OutFileName, FileMode.Create))

            OutFile.Open()

            '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            ContentByte = Writer.DirectContent

            For i = 1 To Pages

                If i > 1 Then OutFile.NewPage()

                AddTemplateImages()

                AddTemplateLines()

                AddTemplateText(DocType, i, Pages)

                AddColumnText()

                AddBarcodeEAN()

                AddBarcode39()

                AddBarcodeQR()


                'THIS WORKS BUT I DO NOT WANT TO ADD DYNAMIC CONTENT HERE 
                'I WANT TO BUILD TEMPLATE FIRST AND THEN GO BACK TO PAGE ONE AND ADD MORE CONTENT

                'AddDynamicContent(i)

            Next

            '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Dim Action As PdfAction

            For i = 1 To Pages

                'Action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(i, New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), Writer)

                Action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(i, New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, -1, 10000, 0), Writer)

                Writer.SetOpenAction(Action)

                'HERE IS THE PROBLEM - I WANT TO GO TO A SPECIFIC PAGE THEN ADD SOME CONTENT
                'WHEN DONE MOVE TO THE NEXT PAGE ADD SOME MORE CONTENT AND SO AND SO FORTH

                'BUT ALL THE CONTENT ENDS UP ON THE LAST PAGE REGARDLESS OF ME MOVING FROM PAGE TO PAGE

                'HOW DO I MOVE THE CURSOR or INSERTION POINT TO A LOCAL PAGE I HAVE CALLED
                'AND ADD NEW Chunks/Phrases/Paragraphs TO THAT PAGE

                AddDynamicContent(i)

            Next

            'GO BACK TO PAGE 1

            Action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), Writer)

            Writer.SetOpenAction(Action)

            '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            OutFile.Close()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub AddDynamicContent(ByVal PageNumber As Integer)

    'JUST TESTING RIGHT NOW

    ContentByte.BeginText()

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ContentByte.SetFontAndSize(FontByName("TimesNewRoman"), 8)
    ContentByte.SetTextMatrix(58.0F, 333.0F)
    ContentByte.ShowText("DYNAMIC CONTENT ON PAGE " & PageNumber.ToString)

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ContentByte.EndText()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

iText(Sharp) flushes all the content of a page to the OutputStream as soon as possible. Why? Because iText was written to produce PDFs in web applications where high speed and low memory use is of the essence.

This means that when you've triggered a new page, there is no going back. There are of course some workarounds, such as

- using a PdfTemplate (for instance to add "page X of Y" because you usually don't know Y until you've added the final page).
- creating a PDF in two goes (once with `PdfWriter`, then manipulate it with `PdfStamper`)
- creating multiple PDFs and then concatenate them with `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`.

By the way: it's quite funny to see somebody using an open action in this way. If you'd read the PDF reference, you'd discover that an open action is an action that is triggered when you open a PDF in Adobe Reader. Whoever told you that it could be used to move from page to page whilst programming was pulling your leg ;-)

Also: you could save yourself an enormous amount of time by reading the documentation: http://itextpdf.com/book (of which I'm the author)

Comment: Bruno, thanks for your help. I did purchase your book and it's a great reference. I've only started using iTextSharp a week ago (and I love it) so I'm still in unfamiliar territory. I can add dynamic content as I build each page since I would have already determine the data needed before creating a PDF (just wanted to isolate each process layer from another instead of drilling down during a debugging session - I could turn processes off and on, as needed). But now that you have pointed out that flushing content occurs my initial intent needs to be revised. again, thank you!

Comment: Your design needs to be changed, but your initial intent can still be preserved if you use one of the workarounds I suggested ;-)